# how to compare and replace a whole line in unix/Linux for multiple files

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I need help with replacing files having only "-" in then with "dues". Here's an example:

#### file1.txt

```
qbc
-
20-11-2015
trv
```

#### file2.txt

```
-
-
21-22-2015
Non-veg
```

#### file 3.txt

```
var
dell
-
```

I need help with something that will replace the complete line having "-" only. I tried with `sed 's/-/dues/g'` but this replaces "-" in dates and other places. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use anchors? `s/^-$/dues/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
 sed 's/^-$/dues/g'
```

Comment: Ohh.. Yess... Anyhow we will have one one "-" in a line.

Comment: guys, thanks let me try it on my server, if it works will mark this as working, thanks a lot for your quick help. Appreciate it a lot.